# Minify CSS Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, optimization, minified-js

It possibile to fix this issue?
Where is the file that i can minify?
How can i find it?
Thanks :)
[image]

Magento 2.2.2 CE

[image]

Comment: I think you can set it from the admin configuration to allow css and js minification

Comment: In admin > stores > configuration > Advanced > Developer > JavaScript or CSS settings > minify

Comment: Is already active!

Answer (score 0):

If you enable production mode, file will merge automatically. 
If you enable developer mode,  there is option in backend to  merged

Comment: Is already active! But gtmetrix it gives me the same error!